# AngularJS call common functions in a directive template

Tags: angularjs, function, directive

I'm very new to AngularJS (from a Java & JQuery background) and trying to understand the "Angular Way" of doing everything, particularly directives.

I would like some help understanding where I should put some helper functions (not specific to a particular controller) which can be called by my template code used by the directive. My functions, in this case, would only be used by the template (therefore the directive).

Specific example: I will have many tables that I want paginated.  Pagination will work similarly for each table. Each table will have their own controller to fetch the data from the server. So, I'm assuming a directive would be a good way to reuse the code.

I created a directive & a template which uses the particular data to show Next and Previous pagination links.  They work well.

**Question**:  In the code below, where should I put the definitions for isFirstPage(page) and isLastPage(page)? I do not want them on every controller for every table which requires pagination.  I also don't think it best to define them at a global level since they are only relevant to pagination.  It seems I should be able to define them directly in the directive.  I tried defining them in the link function.  That sort of worked, but they were called far more than the expected 3 times (it was about 10-20) when the view was loaded.  Plus, a few of the times show errors in the console (Cannot read property 'number' of undefined). And, the documentation says the link function is primarily to manipulate the DOM.  For all those reasons, it seems like the link function is perhaps the wrong place to define them.

Directive:

```
.directive('pagination', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'shared/partials/pagination-links.html'
});
```

Sample Controller (relevant pieces) - all will be similar with different default sort & page sizes & services. Here I define $scope.page and $scope.paginationBaseUrl to be used in the directive template because they contain data particular view and table. These work well.

```
var table1Controllers = angular.module('rmApp.table1Controllers', ['rmApp.Table1Services']);

table1Controllers.controller('Table1Controller', ['$scope', '$location', 'Table1Service'
                                        function ($scope, $location, Table1Service) {

    var search = $location.search();
    var page = search.page||0;
    var size = search.size||20;
    var sort = search.sort||'id,asc';

    var table1Page = Table1Service.get({page:page, size:size, sort:sort}, function() {
        $scope.page = table1Page.page; //this is an object from server with several attributes 
        $scope.paginationBaseUrl = $location.path() + "?size=" + size + "&sort=" + sort;
    });
}]);
```

View HTML: simply call the directive after the table:
    ...

Template HTML snippet (ideal). page and paginationBaseUrl are (and must be) defined on each controller with their particular data.  This is a snippet.  I use more attributes on the page object. My Question is where to define isFirstPage(page) and isLastPage(page):

```
<nav>
        <li ng-class="{disabled: **isFirstPage(page)**}">
            <a ng-show="!isFirstPage(page)" ng-href="#{{paginationBaseUrl}}&page={{page.number - 1}}">Prev</a>
            <span ng-show="isFirstPage(page)">Prev</span>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{disabled: **isLastPage(page)**}">
            <a ng-show="!isLastPage(page)" ng-href="#{{paginationBaseUrl}}&page={{page.number + 1}}">Next</a>
            <span ng-show="isLastPage(page)">Next</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Functions I want to call, example:
    isFirstPage: function(pageInfo) {
        return pageInfo.number === 0;
    }

In this case, these functions are pretty basic & I can just hardcode them, but I know I will encounter similar issues, so I would like to know the right way to do this.  Please also let me know if there is a better way to accomplish something like this pagination directive.  Maybe ngInclude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are getting of method being called two to three times is okay. From the angular documentation:

> The {{ }} are a declarative way of specifying data binding locations
>   in the HTML. **AngularJS will automatically update this text whenever
>   the function inside {{ }} return value changes.**

So you can keep your those functions in link function of directive and just handle the null values.

There is already things available for this build by angular UI team. Check it out: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

Comment: Thanks for the info on the calls 3 times.  I moved them from a link function to a controller function in the directive because it felt a little better.  The bootstrap angularjs directives are great!  I can't believe I hadn't found them.  Thanks so much.  I will definitely use some.